# What is better for performance? Infinitive loop with if or normal loop?

Tags: c++, loops

i often see game engines doing:

```
for(;;) if(!frame()) break;
```

Why arent they just writing:

```
while(frame());
```

or if they want to use for:

```
for(;frame(););
```

is it possible that with for(;;) or while (true) the compiler can optimize more because the condition is always true?!

Comment: Did you check the assembly output of the compiler? Try it there: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Using gcc.godbolt.org, you can easily verify, that there are no difference in terms of generated code.

Comment: I suspect it's just a matter of style, and not of trying to make the most efficient loop.  It would depend on the compiler and in my opinion would not be worth the time trying to save a few assembly instructions in such cases.

Comment: the answer to such questions is always the same. What is faster? Measure. Why? Look at the compiler output

Comment: None of those are infinite loops (unless `frame()` always returns a true value). And the phrase "normal loop" in your title is at best ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is horses for courses.

Any good optimising compiler will generate the same code in these circumstances.

Old-fashioned folk rely heavily on `for(;;)` as most mainsteam compilers don't generate a warning for that when warnings are set "normally". In my opinion at least `while(frame());` is a little clearer although some folk don't like empty loop bodies, and the loop body of the first way is not empty.

Comment: I agree with your points. `while (frame()) {}` is probably clearer than just the semi-colon though.

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference on for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for):

> The above syntax [a for loop] produces code **equivalent** to:
>
> ```
> {
>
>     init_statement
>     while ( condition ) {
>
>         statement
>         iteration_expression ;
>
>     } 
>
> }
> ```

Compilers do not read cppreference, but they also do know that each for loop can be written as a while loop and vice-versa.

The reason you see it often is probably a matter of convention. And we can only guess why it was choosen. Let me speculate...

Consider this loop:

```
for (int i=0;i < N; ++i);
{
    // do something
}
```

Can you spot the mistake? Good compiler warn about it, but in my opinion the potential for such mistakes or to confuse a loop without body with such mistake is reason enough to avoid loops without body when it is possible for no cost.

> is it possible that with for(;;) or while (true) the compiler can
>   optimize more because the condition is always true?!

No, effectively the condition is the same in all three versions.

Comment: The long time convention going back to early C was to use for(;;) as an infinite loop. Never saw a reason why, it just was the way to do one.

Comment: @rm1948 i see. Note that the question was why make the loop Infinite in the first place.

Comment: Note I didn't provide an answer to the OP but just added a comment to another answer.